# How to make work powershell Add-Member with object references?

Tags: powershell

I have some troubles with `Add-Member` and references `[ref]`. They are does not work togeter :-(

The code:

```
function ObjPropAdd([ref]$obj, $name, $value)
{
    # Failed: object reference does not work
    $obj | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name $name –Value $value
}

function ObjPropRemove([ref]$obj, $name)
{
    # Success: object reference is work
    $obj.value.PSObject.Properties.Remove($name)
}

$obj = [PsCustomObject]@{ var1 = 'val1'; var2 = 'val2' }
Write-Host ($obj | ConvertTo-Json)

$obj | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name "var3" –Value "val3" # Success: Add-Member is works
Write-Host ($obj | ConvertTo-Json)

ObjPropAdd ([ref]$obj) "var4" "val4"    # Failed: object reference does not work
Write-Host ($obj | ConvertTo-Json)

ObjPropRemove ([ref]$obj) "var1"        # Success: object reference is works
Write-Host ($obj | ConvertTo-Json)
```

Result:

```
{
    "var1":  "val1",
    "var2":  "val2"
}
{
    "var1":  "val1",
    "var2":  "val2",
    "var3":  "val3"
}
{
    "var1":  "val1",
    "var2":  "val2",
    "var3":  "val3"
}
{
    "var2":  "val2",
    "var3":  "val3"
}
```

My variable `var4` was missed.

Thank you.

Comment: If you set a breakpoint inside the function you will see `$obj` is not your object but a wrapper. Anyway, there's no apparent need for `[ref]` so why do you use it?

Comment: Yes, really this is PSReference not PsCustomObject. This is reference. But in any case the question remains in force: how to use `[ref]$obj` with `Add-Member`?
About why - I prefer references instead returning objects when I have manipulations with objectes through support functions in most cases. Do not forget that the return value - this is copying (and overhead). E.g. if you make 1 million modifications and in each modification you return objects then you will have 1 million redundant objectcopy operations (maybe not big problem for small objects but very big problem for big objects) ;-)

Comment: Objects are always references so no need for `[ref]`. As you can see in the debugger the passed object is `$obj.Value`

Comment: Note, that using pipeline and invoking a function is exactly what makes your 10000000 repetitions slow.

Comment: Perfect. I did not know. A lot of thanks.